# SQL query for data extraction from two tables

Tags: sql

I that bean a long time since i have done anything with a sql database regarding queries.
I have two tables:

- `Player`: `id, name, surname`
- `Team`: `id, team_name, player1_id, player2_id`

How can i write a select query to get a output such as `team_name`, `1st_player_name`, `2nd_player_name`?

I'm repeating the basics but this could give me a jump start.

Comment: Look up a tutorial on SQL joins. http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
SELECT
    t.team_Name,
    p1.name + ' ' + p1.surname AS '1st_player_name',
    p2.name + ' ' + p2.surname AS '2nd_player_name'
FROM
    team t
INNER JOIN 
    player p1 ON t.player1_id = p1.id
INNER JOIN 
    player p2 ON t.player2_id = p2.id
```

You basically need to join the team to the player table twice - once for each of the two players. Since I assume a team always must have both a player #1 and #2, you can use an `INNER JOIN` for each - this means it will match the team and player tables on equality (of the `team.player1_id = player.id` and `team.player2_id = player.id`) between those tables.